# How to format a date range (with only one year string) in different locale's in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, date, localization, nsdateformatter

The date string in English: `Jan 18 - Jan 26, 2018`

Incorrect Korean date string: `Jan 18 - 2018 Jan 26`

What should happen in Korean: `2018 Jan 18 - Jan 26` (not exactly correct Korean, just referring to the location of the year. See accepted answer to see proper Korean date format)

Right now this requires to date formatters, but you have to hardcode which date formatter has the year, so the Korean date doesn't look right.

Is this possible to do in Swift/Objc without just putting the year string on both sides of the date range?

Comment: Why don't you just format it according to the user's locale?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, I was formatting it according to locale but only for individual dates. `DateIntervalFormatter` that maddy brought up solved my problem. Didn't know that was a thing.

Comment: Ah, I see. Cheers! (Is "Jan" even valid in Korean?)

Comment: @Alexander probably not...I was referring mostly to the ordering of the year. As you can see in the answer below the truly correct Korean date interval is all numeric

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `DateIntervalFormatter`:

```
let sd = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2018, month: 1, day: 18))!
let ed = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2018, month: 1, day: 26))!
let dif = DateIntervalFormatter()
dif.dateStyle = .medium
dif.timeStyle = .none
dif.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
let resEN = dif.string(from: sd, to: ed)
dif.locale = Locale(identifier: "ko_KR")
let resKO = dif.string(from: sd, to: ed)
```

This results in:

> Jan 18 – 26, 2018
>   2018. 1. 18. ~ 2018. 1. 26.

The output isn't exactly what you show in your question but the output is appropriate for the given locales.